# Spring boot data rest - entity validation parameter from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I use spring boot data rest to receive a json, create an object based on it and persist it.

I have some problem with the validation.

The entity contains a String where only one value is acceptable. The correct value has to be configured in the application.properties. 
I try to use @Pattern for validation but it doesn't work.

My Entity:

```
@Entity
public class DataObject {

@Size(max=200)
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "{app.text}")
private String req_part1_comment;

getter, setter...
```

The application.properties:

app.text=Correct text value

As I can see, it can't read the value out of the property file.

How can I add that parameter from the application.properties to validate that String in the Entity?

Thank you,